# React app unable to access root's env file

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, environment-variables, mern

Context: 
- MERN stack app
- Deployed to Heroku
- React app created with `create-react-app`

Here is my folder structure:

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0uoI.png)

In my server `app.js`, I can access the `.env` variables by requiring it like this: `require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' });`

I am trying to access the env variables on my React app, but I cannot seem to access the variables in the root `.env` file, and I cannot seem to specify the path in React (can I?) for the .env like in `server/app.js`.

The only way I can get it to read any `.env` variable value is if I move the `.env` file to the `client` directory, so my workaround for now is to move `.env` to my client directory and update the code in my server to require it as such: `require('dotenv').config({ path: '../client/.env' });`

This workaround fixes it, but is there a better way/best practice to allow for the `.env` file be in the root folder?

Do I need to eject create-react-app and set up some custom configurations?

More info:

My local .env file contains:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:5000
```

My client/package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Hi Sabrina, did you figure out the .env file issue? I'm in exactly the same boat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, miss understood your question.

In `create-react-app` you don't have to require the dotenv module, ref: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Are you sure your local environmentis `development`?

Comment: Oh, sorry if I wasn't being very clear. I do have my environment variables specified in my Heroku config. The issue at hand is about getting my local React app to access the .env file.

Comment: Hi Sabrina, did you figure out the .env file issue? I'm in exactly the same boat. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue... Did you manage to fix it?